# PHPMailer 1.5 / Sourceforge not working?

Tags: php, email, sourceforge

I have been trying to get the latest version of phpmailer from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/

but I keep getting "file not found" / "unable to load mirrors" errors. I tried other files it seems like sourceforge is messed up right now or something is wrong with my connection to it.

Any ideas? And if it is sourceforge does anyone have/know where I can get an alt link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get 500 error

Try here. I downloaded and opened it.

http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/download.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/p/ph/phpmailer/

Dam

Answer (score 0):

I do get 500 error,
you know there is something wrong with SF site, 
I've also needed to upgrade my server and tried to download something, but it does not working. and same error I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this [PHPMailer 5](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=phpmailer) the same as what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

To call that class we need 3 files. They are:

1. class.phpmailer.php
2. class.smtp.php
3. phpmailer.lang-et.php

if you not want to change PluginDir put that files in one folder with your source which will use to call that class.
Don't forget to setting the parameter as according to your mail server. And it's available at the file testmail.php at the folder test.

Good luck